# Таймер без setInterval и setTimeout

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

Среда разработки использует движок JavaScript, но не поддерживает **setInterval** и **setTimeout**.
Как сделать таймер используя счетчик
**Tickcount()** - количество тиков сервера (в зависимости от выбранных настроек **50** или **100** тиков в секунду, каждый тик соответственно с интервалом **20** или **10** мс)?

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/WNRRVyO  вот без timeout и без interval

Comment: @MaximLensky а может на обычном CSS сделать?

Comment: В общем случае - никак. Если ваша среда не поддерживает такие базовые для языка вещи - нет никаких гарантий что она хоть что-нибудь поддерживает.

Comment: А для получения ответа в частном случае укажите о какой среде разработки вообще речь.

Comment: Уже решил, использовав requestAnimationFrame

Answer (score 3):

А зачем JS? Может на CSS это сделать? (не открывайте не в хроме)

```css
@property --milliseconds {
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0;
  syntax: '<integer>';
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background: hsl(10, 10%, 10%);
}

.counter {
  position: relative;
  counter-reset: ms var(--milliseconds);
  animation: count 10s steps(100) infinite;
}

.counter:after {
  content: counter(ms);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 5rem;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

@keyframes count {
  to {
    --milliseconds: 100;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="counter"></div>
```

Comment: CSS недоступен в этой среде. Я уже решил проблему воспользовавшись requestAnimationFrame.

Answer (score -1):

Если вы работаете с библиотекой `Qt5`, для `QJSValue` вам потребуется создать `setTimeout` и `setInterval` самостоятельно. Дело в том, что метод [call](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsvalue.html#call) у QJSValue позволяет **исполнить код в синхронном виде**, внутренняя реализация не содержит `event loop`. Думаю, интерфейс QJSValue будет типовым для любой реализации JS движка...

> Когда я был студентом, я разрабатывал подобный проект и [выложил исходный код](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/quite) на GitHub...

```
class TimerGlobalObjectExtension : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    explicit TimerGlobalObjectExtension(QObject* parent = nullptr);
    virtual ~TimerGlobalObjectExtension();
  public slots:
    QJSValue setTimeout(QJSValue handler, QJSValue timeout);
    QJSValue clearTimeout(QJSValue timeout);
};

...

TimerGlobalObjectExtension* extension = new TimerGlobalObjectExtension();
QJSEngine *eval = new QJSEngine();
QJSValue managed = eval->newQObject(extension);
eval->globalObject().setProperty("setTimeout", managed.property("setTimeout"));
eval->globalObject().setProperty("clearTimeout", managed.property("clearTimeout"));
```